# Why all Java Errors are not considered fatal in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, error-handling

In the [Scala 2.13 docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/util/control/NonFatal$.html), the description for `NonFatal` is:

> Extractor of non-fatal Throwables. Will not match fatal errors like VirtualMachineError (for example, OutOfMemoryError and StackOverflowError, subclasses of VirtualMachineError), ThreadDeath, LinkageError, InterruptedException, ControlThrowable.

Why are only these errors / exceptions considered fatal? In Java8, there are more [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) subclasses, each of which "indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch". Example of these include `CoderMalfunctionError`, `FactoryConfigurationError`, and `IOError`. I won't claim to know the precise meanings of these errors, but if Java thinks these errors are serious problems, why shouldn't Scala also think the same?

Comment: Is the list exhaustive? It says *for example*

Comment: Yes it is. You can check in the Scala source code: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.1/src/library/scala/util/control/NonFatal.scala#L41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SethTisue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10166#issuecomment-367808949) asked a similar quesiton

> @viktorklang tbh I don't really understand why any Error would be
> considered NonFatal. the JVM already has the Error vs non-Error
> distinction, I've never been especially clear on why NonFatal adds an
> additional level of classification.

and [viktorklang](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10166#issuecomment-367812820) replied

> @SethTisue «An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious
> problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. » -
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html
>
> The problem is that there are quite a few unreasonable applications
> out there, and since Error is extendable it is impossible to say that
> all Errors are fatal.

Hence it seems that because there are sufficient number of applications in the wild which violate the intended semantics of `Error`, then Scala contributors were hesitant to define them all as fatal.

Also consider gitter discussion around the following [comment](https://gitter.im/scala/contributors?at=5a8f1c77c3c5f8b90df10d2a)

> Edmund Noble @edmundnoble Feb 22 2018 19:39
>
> Afaik Error is supposed to
> be fatal Though as @Ichoran says there are exceptions, I just don't
> think they're well-defined, and you basically need to whitelist the
> errors you think aren't fatal